# I would like to use an ldap query for users with direct reports (aka all managers)

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I am looking for an LDAP query that returns all users that have direct reports (aka all managers) could anyone help me out with that?

Comment: welcome, did you done research? have you maybe used chatgpt? I don't see anykind of research inhere. please read carefully [ask]

Comment: Do you want to query if they have a direct reports, or do you also want to query if they have a direct reports and if so who are the direct reports?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in comments, did you bother doing any research? As a hint, you can't directly query "reports" from a manager account, but you can query the `manager` attribute for each account. Naturally, you'll end up with a lot of duplicate results, assuming each manager has multiple staff.

Because I'm feeling nice, here's a Powershell version of the answer (requires the ADDS Powershell module) - I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to extract the manager names and get rid of the dupes.

```
Get-Aduser -Ldapfilter '(manager=*)' -properties manager
```

Comment: LeeM,

Yes I bothered doing research. I also posted on Microsoft forums and didn't get any backlash from angry users that don't know how to use LDAP Queries.

(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(manager=*))

Comment: Your Q didn't specify what method you used or your actual query, so my answer gave an AD Powershell example of a potential answer. If you want to query specifically user accounts more efficiently via pure LDAP, use `(samAccountType=805306368)` (instead of objectclass and objectcategory). The core of my answer was that you can't query reports, you can only query managers, so the logic needs to be reversed from your original query (I'm guessing, we *don't know* what it was). And still no acknowledgement whether having that info re querying each user for managers actually helped you or not.

Answer (score 0):

LeeM,

Yes I bothered doing research. I also posted on Microsoft forums and didn't get any backlash from angry users that don't know how to use LDAP Queries.

(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(manager=*))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573091)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(manager=*))
```

Remember to adjust the query based on your specific AD schema and structure.